# Jira REST api syntax issue

Tags: api, rest, curl, jira, jira-rest-api

I have one issue type called "Support Task". I am trying a jql like the below:

`curl -D- -u $username:$password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "$jiraurl/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%20%3D%20DEM%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20"Support%20Task"%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Open%20AND%20updatedDate%20>%3D%20-1h`

Due to the space in support task, it is not working.

```
{"errorMessages":["Error in the JQL Query: Expecting either 'OR' or 'AND' but got 'Task'. (line 1, character 39)"],"errors":
```

When I pass other issue types without space it is working.

Tried even `"Support+Task"` but didn't help. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: I had to replace all " with %22 and this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `jql` query is being URL-encoded wrong, that's why it tries to treat it differently. You encode the whole string, but you should encode only logical pieces of query, with `&` between the parameters.

[Based on the manual](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-query-issues), they do it a bit differently, generic syntax would be:

```
rest/api/2/search?jql=project=DEM&issuetype=Support Task&.....
```